# Write lines in assembly with out going back to the start of the line (stair step text)

Tags: assembly, newline, dos, x86-16

I can't find a way to write words in assembly in a waterfall struct, example:

```
one
   two
      three
```

I tried to seprate between 10 and 13 but it didnt work. here is the code so far:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA
MyProgram DB 'word1',10,'word2',10,'word3','$'    


.CODE

ProgStart:
MOV AX,@DATA
MOV BX,OFFSET MyProgram
MOV DS,AX

MOV AH,9
MOV DX,OFFSET MyProgram
INT 21h

MOV AH,4ch
INT 21h
```

Comment: try BIOS INT 10h Fn 0Eh, but terminate string with 0 instead of '$'

Comment: @AlexanderZhak BIOS teletype function 0Eh does not depend on any delimiter. It outputs the single character in the AL register.

Comment: @user3819295 In DOS 6.2 your program works just fine. Are you working on a LINUX based system? Perhaps changing code 10 (\n) into 11 (\v) might work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to go back to the start of the line because you need a line break. By nature, line break moves cursor to the beginning of the next line. With linebreaks you need one blank space and a counter to display the blank space n times. This counter increases with every line you display. Example made in EMU8086 (just copy, paste and run) :

```
.STACK 100h
.DATA

text   DB 'hello world',13,10,'$'
space  DB ' $' ;BLANK SPACE.
spaces dw 1  ;COUNTER FOR BLANK SPACES.


.CODE

MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX

  mov bx,10 ;HOW MANY LINES TO DISPLAY.

display_text:  

  mov cx, spaces   
display_spaces: 
  mov ah, 9
  mov dx, offset space
  int 21h
  loop display_spaces ;CX-1. IF CX!=0 : DISPLAY NEXT SPACE.

  inc spaces ;MOVE NEXT INDENT ONE SPACE TO THE RIGHT.
;DISPLAY TEXT.
  MOV AH,9
  MOV DX,OFFSET text
  INT 21h         

  dec bx ;LINES COUNTER.
  mov cx, bx
  loop display_text


MOV AH,4ch
INT 21h
```

If you want to indent by one space, increase the counter by 1, if you want to indent by two spaces, increase by 2, and so on.

Now WITHOUT line breaks, by using GOTOXY, this way you don't need to go back to the beginning of the line because there are no line breaks :

```
.STACK 100h
.DATA

text  DB 'hello world',13,10,'$'
row   db 1  ;LINE NUMBER.
col   db 1

.CODE

MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX

  mov cx,10 ;HOW MANY LINES TO DISPLAY.

display_text:  
;GOTOXY.
  mov ah, 2
  mov bh, 0
  mov dl, col
  mov dh, row
  int 10h ;BIOS SCREEN SERVICES.
;DISPLAY TEXT.
  MOV AH,9
  MOV DX,OFFSET text
  INT 21h         

  inc row ;Y COORDINATE ONE LINE DOWN.
  inc col ;X COORDINATE ONE COLUMN RIGHT.
  loop display_text


MOV AH,4ch
INT 21h
```

Answer (score 0):

Re: @AlexanderZhak BIOS teletype function 0Eh does not depend on any delimiter. It outputs the single character in the AL register.

This works as follows:

```
print:
mov bx, 7
mov ah, 0x0e
next_char:
lodsb
test al, al
jz exit
int 0x10
jmp next_char
exit:
ret
```

print proc receives pointer to string in DS:SI
Call it as

```
mov si, offset my_string
call print
```

Much simpler and faster than moving cursor